# How to Model Differential Gravitational Field from Vectors?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, vector-fields, tidal-effect

The tides are caused by differences in the gravitational field of the moon on the near side and far side of the earth. If I set this gravitational field as a vector field using Newton's Law of Gravitation, how can the difference in this field be represented? When gravity is represented in one-dimension, the differential gravity is found simply by taking the derivative of Newton's Law of Gravitation. So in other words, how can differential gravity be represented from a 3-dimensional gravitational vector field?

Comment: Note that you can take the [gradient of a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector).

Comment: That solves my issue. Didn't know about taking gradients of vector fields, only scalar fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent of the derivative for a vector field $\bf v$ - the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector) $\nabla {\bf v}$. This will work just fine on a gravitational field.

Comment: Really just turning the comment from Kyle Kanos into an answer.